# Edit RSS feed with Nokogiri and XPath?

Tags: ruby, xpath, rss, nokogiri

I want to edit a node of each item of an RSS feed in Ruby with Nokogiri and XPath.

I can get the value of this node but I can not edit them:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(open("http://www.pcinpact.com/rss/news.xml"))

doc.xpath('//item').each do |i|
  pp i.xpath('title').first.text
end
```

I get the value of the `title` node in each `item` node.
I want to edit the "content" but I can't find how with `xpath`.
Obviously I want to get my original XML with the modifications.

Any idea?

Comment: When you ask a question, we expect a minimal example of the input data, and a sample of the output you want. You're asking potential answerers to run the code, and extract the data and minimize it just to help you. Instead, you need to help us help you, and do that up front. Where in your code to you try to change the node? We need to see your attempt.

Comment: Note that XPath is a *query* language. It does not allow you to edit a document. It merely lets you retrieve things from it.

Comment: The input data is too large to be here. 
I tried to show methods of xpath with .methods but I don't find anything interesting.
I looked on Nokogiri website but I've found nothing with xpath.

Comment: I've found at_xpath method ? Do you think I can made replacements with this method ?

Comment: The input data can be summarized to provide an example that you're working with, or you can cobble up something that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: "Do you think I can made replacements with this method ?" When you read the documentation, did it give you any suggestion it could be used for editing, or was it for searching?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For setting the content use the `content=` method.

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(open("http://www.pcinpact.com/rss/news.xml"))

doc.xpath('//item').each do |i|
  pp i.xpath('title').first.content = "My new title"
end
```

For more on how to manipulate a document in Nokogiri, check out "[Modifying an HTML / XML Document](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/modifying_an_html_xml_document.html)".

Comment: I already thought I had tried but it's work the way I want ! Thanks at all !

I solved my problem by using at_xpath but it was not very good.